# Determining the standard deviation with only the mean, median, mode, high score, low score, range, and population size

Tags: probability, statistics

Is it even possible without the data set? I'm pretty sure it isn't and I don't know how my teacher would be able to solve it without the data set but he said it was possible.
The given values are that the mean, median, and mode are all equal to 100. The population size is 30, and the high score is 130 while the low score is 70. Even with these information, looking at the formula for standard deviation, the standard deviation can vary wildly as there is no information of the data set, am I right?

Comment: As far as I can tell you are correct that you cannot deduce the standard deviation from the given data (it is possible to bound it however). The only way I could see this being possible is if there are extra assumptions being made.

Comment: If there are no additional assumptions, this is impossible. Check out the population with $9$ values equal to $70$, $9$ values equal to $130$ and $12$ values are equal to $100$, vs. the population where one value is $70$, one value is $130$ and the remaining $28$ values are $100$. (First example slightly contrived because of the mode.)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've been thinking. Our teacher said we can just base it on the formula but that's impossible considering I neither have a data set or a sum of squares of the data set. My classmates and I have been trying to find out how to even tackle this problem with no data set given.